# jQuery for responsive web design

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey Guys, I am new to jQuery.
Now I've been reading some blogs describing how javascript can responsively do magical stuff. There are lots of plugins out there but I guess for my work I don't need them.
I am trying to have dynamic images loaded according to the screen resolution but somehow I am unable to set the dimensions for the screen.
Here is my code:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() >= 1000 && $(window).width()<=1400 ){    
        $('#myFirstImage').attr('src', 'img/bgLow.jpg');
    }
});
```

Now as the browser is resized javascript will look for dimensions.
Somehow I am unable to set something within 1000 and 1500 px range. Can you guys tell me  where I am doing this if-logic wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what is failing?  Is it detecting the window width but not updating the image?  Or not detecting the window width at all?  What does your HTML look like?

Comment: Using [`window.matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia) would be a much better option here

Comment: @Bojangles If you don't mind excluding most IE that is.. x)

Comment: Please add the HTML for your image.  http://jsfiddle.net/M9GBL/ shows the window resize working

Comment: also good to add a variable outside ( say, `var bp1=false` ) the resize function so you are not firing  the `img src` change repeatedly. Within your if statement setting `bp1=true` and then not running the if statement if 'bp1' is already set to true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the common code in a function, then bind the event, and call the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Optimisation: store the references outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window);

    function checkWidth() {
        var windowsize = $window.width();
        if (windowsize >= 1000 && windowsize <= 1400) {
            $('#myFirstImage').attr('src', 'img/bgLow.jpg');
        }
    }

    // Execute on load
    checkWidth();

    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidth);
});
```

Comment: if i have to run this functionality on rbowser load then i have to run the checkWidth() function on document load right?

Comment: And if i have to work on low resolutions too i have to do this on window load  $(window).resize(checkWidthForLow);

Comment: AFAIK, `$(document).ready` function event executes a bit earlier than `window.onload()` and called once the DOM is loaded on your page. It will not wait for the images, frames to get fully load. It means that it is the earliest stage in page load process. So, use the `document.ready` event if you want to intervene "early" in the rendering process, without waiting for the images to load. Read more about go through the link [how $document.ready() is different from window.onload()](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2013/08/document-ready-vs-window-onload.html)

Comment: Im guessing this got it working because the OP had the script incorrectly **above** the  markup. Wouldn't just moving the script under be better?

Comment: I like your style of the reusable code, the protected global scope and selector caching btw

Comment: @RobSedgwick there is this thing. If we resize the browser again and again will it reload the whole images again or can we cache them?

Comment: @designerNProgrammer I just added a comment to your main post to address that - " also good to add a variable outside ( say, var bp1=false ) the resize function so you are not firing the img src change repeatedly. Within your if statement setting bp1=true and then not running the if statement if 'bp1' is already set to true "

Comment: Yes, it is standard practice to move the script to the bottom of your page because when a browser loads script, it does not spawn a new thread to do so, so it won't run until the DOM has finished being instantiated. What this means for your users is that they will see a blank screen. Much better to have them see the full(ish) page as then it doesn't look like it has stalled.

Comment: @RobSedgwick All boils down to good Javascript standard practices :)

Comment: aye. all good stuff. I thought it worth as a mention, as the `doc.ready` here might have skipped the real reason the original code was not working

Comment: Spot on, cheers for mentioning it! One of those niggly cases we sometimes fail to notice.

Comment: @RobSedgwick i am still confused how to use the var bp . can you do me a code fiddle or something. thanks.

Comment: @designerNProgrammer - ok i will use chridam's neat code as the base - brb

Comment: @RobSedgwick i am waiting my pal. Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: getting pizza and coffee, what do you expect  : ) - okay study this -  http://jsfiddle.net/nyppg/1/. my SO time is up, but you should get the idea in this code. all the best

Comment: @rob still confused.!

Comment: @designerNProgrammer, it stops the re fire of the `if` statement *if* already set by using a variable outside the `resize` function. Lets not spam Chridams post here and ( as it is a new question ) post up a new question.

Comment: @RobSedgwick please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111795/changing-some-functionality-according-to-screen-size-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Responsive Design is commonly referred to as being a CSS job, but, as you see, there is often the need for javascript to do things as different 'sizes' too.

## JS method 1

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) { 
   body { background-color:orange; }
}
```

JS using `window.match.media` - check [support](http://caniuse.com/matchmedia)

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 320px)");
if(mql.matches) { ...
```

## JS method 2

**CSS**

```
body.small { background-color:orange; }
```

**JS using** `window.resize`

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {
  if($(this).width() < 320px) { $(body).addClass("small"); dosomefunction(); }
});
```

---

*I'm seeing this answers pop in as I type - this is the basic idea .. ( minus checking if classes have been set already and the like )*

---

Quite often a combo of them both is 'the way' using `if(window.matchmedia)` to check before using it

Answer (score -2):

use doument width

```
$(document).width();
```