# changing some functionality according to screen size using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guy I am trying to change the functionality of my web page according to screen resolution.
Now to some extent it's working fine but the problem is that every time I change the resolution the whole functionality has to render again. Say for example if I have to load different versions of an image according to the screen size and I am on medium size, if I resize and I am still on medium resolution the images have to reload again.
Now I am using `$(window).resize(checkMedWidth);` but there must be some way to get hld of loading if i am on medium size.
my code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Optimisation: store the references outside the event handler:
var $window = $(window);

var currentWindowSize;

var flagIs;
$(window).resize(function () {
    currentWindowSize = $window.width();
    if (currentWindowSize >= 0 && currentWindowSize <= 999) {
        $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
        flagIs = "low";

    }
    else if (currentWindowSize >= 1000 && currentWindowSize <= 1336) {

        $('body').css('background-color', 'green');
        flagIs = "high";
        }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Optimisation: store the references outside the event handler:
var $window = $(window),
    currentWindowSize,
    flagIs,
    flagWas = '';

function res() {
    currentWindowSize = $window.width();

//set flag string to LOW if...    
if (currentWindowSize <= 999) {
    flagIs = "low";
}
//set flag string to HIGH if...
else if (currentWindowSize >= 1000 && currentWindowSize <= 1336) {
    flagIs = "high";
}
// on first call function compare zero string flagWas and current string (for example) 'low'
//on other calls function will compare current string and the past string
// if they are different (it happens if user change browser window width AND new window width walk into different width interval) or ( on the first iteration past string = '' and new string =/= '' (just containsa some string, for example 'low' ))
if (flagIs != flagWas)
{
        // if new string is low - so change css to low setting
       if (flagIs == 'low') {
           $('body').css('background-color', 'red');
       }
        // if new string is high - so change css to high setting
       else if (flagIs == 'high') {
           $('body').css('background-color', 'green');
       }
        //after we done with all this just write our present flagString to pastString (so we can use it later for compare like we did it before, variables are global, so we can access them from one iteration to another)
       flagWas = flagIs;
}
}

// Execute function on load
res();

// the same function will be execute each time we resize window
$(window).resize(function () {
   res(); 
});
});
```

AND here goes [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/4EUuY/10/)
Honestly- code in my first answer was better, and it solve your task as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

Merge both your functions **checkLowWidth** and **checkMedWidth** in one and use flags.
For example: **flagWas** and **flagNow**.

1. on page load check window resolution
2. for example it's med, so flagWas = 'med';
3. on window resolution change- check it's new definition - for example it'll be med too, so flagNow = 'med'
4. check if flagNow =/= flagWas
5. in our example flagNow = flagWas = 'med' so do nothing
6. and, for example, if flagNow = 'low' so flagNow =/= flagWas then change sizes/ classes/ etc and after all that flagWas = flagNow (= 'low')

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Optimisation: store the references outside the event handler:
    var $window = $(window),
        flagWas = '';

    function checkWidthTier() {
        var windowsize = $window.width(),
            flagNow;
        if (windowsize <= 1024)
        { flagNow = 'low'; }
        else if (windowsize >= 1025 && windowsize <= 2000)
        { flagNow = 'med'; }
        if (flagNow != flagWas)
        {
           $('body').removeClass(flagWas);
           $('body').addClass(flagNow);
           flagWas = flagNow;
        }
    }

    // Execute on load
    checkWidthTier();

    // Bind event listener
    $(window).resize(checkWidthTier);
});
```

CSS:

```
.low { background: red; }
.med { background: yellow; }
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4EUuY/8/), I changed your code a little.

Comment: can you do a fiddle for me please?

Comment: I am still confused. can you please give me a fiddle.

Comment: why are you using this flagNow != flagWas  ?

Comment: ive created new code in question. can you help me fix it

Comment: Can you please fix the code i did in question witch comments. Oh i am so confused.